# Tkinter quit button

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started learning python and I have a problem that I canno't get a button to close my program. The code:

```
from tkinter import *
import ScoreboardController as SC

class guiController(Frame):

    def open_scoreboard(self):
        scoreBoard = SC.ScoreboardController("scores.txt")
        for x in range(len(scoreBoard)):
            print("Name: {} \nScore: {}". format(scoreBoard[x].name, scoreBoard[x].score))

    def start_game(self):
        pass

    def hide_main_window(self):
        self.score_button.pack_forget()
        self.start_button.pack_forget()


    def create_widgets(self):

        self.frame = Frame(master=None, width=800, height=600)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.start_button = Button(self.frame)
        self.start_button["text"] = "Játék indítása"
        self.start_button["bg"] = "#5E99FF"
        self.start_button["fg"] = "#ffffff"
        self.start_button["command"] = self.start_game
        self.start_button.pack()
        self.start_button.place(x=300, y=455, bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=50, width=200)

        self.score_button = Button(self.frame)
        self.score_button["text"] = "Eredmények"
        self.score_button["bg"] = "#5E99FF"
        self.score_button["fg"] = "#ffffff"
        self.score_button["command"] = self.open_scoreboard
        self.score_button.pack()
        self.score_button.place(x=300, y=400, bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=50, width=200)

        self.quit_button = Button(self.frame)
        self.quit_button["text"] = "Kilépés"
        self.quit_button["bg"] = "#5E99FF"
        self.quit_button["fg"] = "#FFFFFF"
        self.quit_button["command"] = self.destroy()
        self.quit_button.pack()
        self.quit_button.place(x=300, y=510, bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=50, width=200)

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.place()
        self.create_widgets()
```

When I click the button it doesn't do anything (self.quit_button).
The other buttons work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you packing your button then placing your button right after? Why are you writing your buttons in the hardest way?

Comment: I've used Java befor and this way it's easier for me to follow my code.

Comment: Well it is the hardest way to do it. Also you are packing your widgets then placing them. Remove the `pack()` as you are not using it correctly. BTW you code is not testable as is. `ScoreboardController` is not a built in library so I have no idea what to do with this part except try to remove it. Also you do not initialize your class anywhere in your example or show what you are passing as master to it.

Comment: `self.quit_button["command"] = self.destroy()` means to call `destroy` *right now*, and use its return value (most likely `None`) as the command to be used if this button is eventually clicked.  You did it right for the other two buttons, why not this one?

Comment: You will need to destroy `master`, not `self`.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Like @busybear said you need to destroy whatever master is. So if master is your main window or root window then do master.destroy as your command without the `()`.

Comment: Yeah I found the problem. I have the root in my main so somehow I have to figure a way out to destroy the root in main :'D Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's fine if root is in your main. You are passing your root to master are you not? That is what one normally does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fully test your code however here is what you would do when needed to destroy master. Your code was a bit hard to test please in the future do not include stuff that cannot be tested like your `ScoreboardController`. Also I rewrote your buttons to something simpler.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def start_game(self):
        pass

    def hide_main_window(self):
        self.score_button.pack_forget()
        self.start_button.pack_forget()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Játék indítása", bg="#5E99FF", fg="#ffffff")
        self.start_button.pack()

        self.score_button = tk.Button(self, text="Eredmények", bg="#5E99FF", fg="#ffffff", command=self.start_game)
        self.score_button.pack()

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Kilépés", bg="#5E99FF", fg="#ffffff", command=self.master.destroy) # without ()
        self.quit_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack() # root passing to master in the Frame class
    root.mainloop()
```